# Raid5 раздел вернуть не могу

Tags: linux, raid

Иногда контакты плохие приводят к отключении одного диска из raid5 массива. Сейчас уже не могу вернуть диск назад. Ошибка выползает. Что такое неправильный аргумент?

```
# mdadm /dev/md/2 --add /dev/sda5 
mdadm: add new device failed for /dev/sda5 as 3: Invalid argument

# mdadm --brief /dev/md2                     
/dev/md2: 857.19GiB raid5 3 devices, 0 spares. Use mdadm --detail for more detail.

# cat /proc/mdstat                  
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] 
md2 : active raid5 sdb5[4] sdc2[2]
      898834048 blocks super 1.0 level 5, 64k chunk, algorithm 2 [3/2] [_UU]
      
md0 : active raid5 sdb3[1] sda6[4] sdc1[3]
      976768512 blocks super 1.0 level 5, 128k chunk, algorithm 2 [3/3] [UUU]
      bitmap: 2/4 pages [8KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>

# mdadm --detail /dev/md2       
/dev/md2:
           Version : 1.0
     Creation Time : Tue May 31 14:33:33 2016
        Raid Level : raid5
        Array Size : 898834048 (857.19 GiB 920.41 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 449417024 (428.60 GiB 460.20 GB)
      Raid Devices : 3
     Total Devices : 2
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

       Update Time : Sat Oct 31 17:50:30 2020
             State : clean, degraded 
    Active Devices : 2
   Working Devices : 2
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

            Layout : left-symmetric
        Chunk Size : 64K

Consistency Policy : resync

              Name : any:2
              UUID : c4c80dbb:9b5cd068:fe33283e:63397104
            Events : 2813

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       -       0        0        0      removed
       4       8       21        1      active sync   /dev/sdb5
       2       8       34        2      active sync   /dev/sdc2
```

попытка вторая :

```
# dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda5 bs=1M count=200
200+0 records in
200+0 records out
209715200 bytes (210 MB, 200 MiB) copied, 2.12945 s, 98.5 MB/s

# mdadm /dev/md2 --add /dev/sda5 
mdadm: add new device failed for /dev/sda5 as 3: Invalid argument

# dmesg
[ 8463.999268] md: sda5 does not have a valid v1.0 superblock, not importing!
[ 8463.999274] md: md_import_device returned -22
```

Comment: Что в этот момент в dmesg?

Comment: `[ 7177.799814] md: sda5 does not have a valid v1.0 superblock, not importing!
[ 7177.799820] md: md_import_device returned -22` @Alexander Prokoshev

Comment: Занулите начало раздела. Несколько мегабайт нулей туда впихайте через dd и подключите его к массиву снова.

Comment: Уже пытался `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda5 count=10`. Наверное мало? @Alexander Prokoshev

Comment: Ну несколько мегабайт. Просто dd запустите на десяток секунд без указания count - будет достаточно.

Comment: Перегружался... Попробую count=100 @Alexander Prokoshev

Comment: А винт надо поменять. Или контроллер. Или кабель. Видите, на нём уже метаданные портиться начали.

Comment: Ничего не помогает. Надо скорее всего всё перекидывать и новый рейд делать. `md0` - на тех-же дисках. @Alexander Prokoshev

Comment: Не наш метод. Убедитесь, что у раздела sda5 стоит тип fd. Впишите на него двести мегов нулей dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda5 bs=1M count=200. Добавьте в массив снова. Покажите, что в dmesg, если будет ошибка.

Comment: Покажите также и скриншот, захватывающий все эти команды, если можно.

Comment: Почитал. Суперблок 1.0 лежит в конце устройства, так что или затирать хвост, или пробовать через mdadm --zero-superblock, что, как пишут, не всегда работает правильно.

Comment: Это куда же теперь нулить? @Alexander Prokoshev

Comment: Там интересно написано: "Version 1.0 is stored near the end of the device (at least 8K, and less than 12K, from the end)". Ну, вероятно, если сделать seek= до последнего гигабайта, то не промахнётесь. С расчётами не ошибитесь только, а то опять мимо бабахнет :)

Comment: То есть что-то типа `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda5 bs=1M skip=100500`.  Оно завершится само, когде доедет до конца устройства. Если подсчитаете правильно, то оно покажет предсказанную вами цифру в "bytes written" по окончании. Можно и вообще не скипать, просто полтерабайта - это надолго.

Comment: Наконец-то принято. `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda5 bs=1M skip=400000` . Пропускаю 400G, пишу туда нули  и делаю `add`. Сделайте ответ с `dmesg` и ver1.0 и этот злополучный конец. @Alexander Prokoshev

Comment: Ой, я в команде-то skip написал. А надо было seek, как в комментарии перед этим :)

Comment: Нафиг, не хочу ещё ответ писать. Оно ведь не баллов ради, но пользы для. А комментарии и так проиндексируются.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С советами  [Alexander Prokoshev](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/227256/alexander-prokoshev) разобрался. Читаем

```
# dmesg
[ 8463.999268] md: sda5 does not have a valid v1.0 superblock, not importing!
[ 8463.999274] md: md_import_device returned -22
```

Узнаём, что служебная информация рейд массива v1.0 находится в конце раздела. И обнуляем не начало, а конец. Я грубо сделал это так :

```
# dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda5 bs=1M skip=400000
```

Пропускаю 400Gb и обнуляю.
*Можно ещё так:*

```
# mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sda5
```

Следующая попытка добавить раздел уже успешна.

```
# mdadm /dev/md2 --add /dev/sda5
```